# Adding UINavigationBar to a UITabBarController

Tags: iphone, xcode, uinavigationcontroller, uitabbarcontroller

Ok so I actually got to add UINavigationBar inside a UITabBarController using the following tutorial: http://twilloapp.blogspot.com/2009/03/how-to-embed-navigation-controller.html

But now the issue is that whenever I add a new button inside one of the views it just crashes.

For example:

In the first view called FirstViewController I added:

```
IBOutlet UIButton *test;
```

Than I also created:

```
- (IBAction) doSomething:(id)sender;
```

I hook up the test button with the UI in interface builder. But when I run i get:

```
*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSUnknownKeyException', reason: '[<UIViewController 0x3b12e80> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key test.'
```

Not sure what's going on with this.

Does anyone know of a solution?

Also, does anyone know where can I find good pre-built templates for these kinda apps so I can just start working rather than editing and setting things up.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you unarchive the nib file at runtime, it's going to invoke `setTest:aButton` on your controller, which will redirect to `setValue:aButton forKey:@"test"`.  Since it's throwing an exception that it doesn't know what the key `@"test"` means, chances are you forgot to put the `@synthesize test;` in your `FirstViewController.m` file.